# Problems with the IFilter library when compile as x86

Tags: c#, search, indexing, search-engine, ifilter

I have developing a c# application and I use the IFilter library to extract the content of the files. The problem is that the function LoadLibrary doesn't work when compiled to x86.

I would using the library Ifilter in c# application witch run as x86. It's possible ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice example how to use iFilter in C# is on CP http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C

Working on 32b/64b enviroment. Also as x86 app.

Comment: I use this example, but Ifilter doesn't run in x86

Comment: Does anybody have any suggestion to use the library IFilter as x86?

Comment: What IFilter? If exists only in 64b, you of course cant access it.

Comment: I would use the library IFilter in my c# application witch run as x86, but the IFilter doesn't work as x86

Comment: I think it's impossible to load 64b ifilter from 32b app. But you can make 64bit console app. And call it from yours 32bit app ;]